# Rendering action from base controller, getting route not defined error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I have a base controller all my other controllers inherit from, inside the base controller are  2`ActionResult` that is common to every page on my site. When I try to use `Html.RenderAction` to call either of these actions from a View I get the error

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

I have checked and the `Action` is set to `public` and the names are spelled right. What am I doing wrong?

The call: `@{ Html.RenderAction("SectionNavigation"); }`

The Action:

`[Route("SectionNavigation")]
public ActionResult SectionNavigation()`

As you can see I am also using Attribute Routing as well. I also tried updated the call to specify `Base` as the controller but that did not change anything.

Comment: The first parameter of `RenderAction` is the **action name**, not the route name. If you're rendering a view that is generated using controller other than the one that defines the `SectionNavigation` action, you'll have to specify the controller name as well: `@Html.RenderAction("SecondNavigation", "YourControllerName")`. If you're using Areas, you'll have to include the area name as well: `@Html.RenderAction("SecondNavigation", "YourControllerName", new { Area = "MyAreaName" })`.

Comment: @haim770 I did try specifying the controller name but got the same error. As you can see from my post the name of the route and action are the same so the call should have worked. I am using areas but these two controllers are not in an area but I will try specifying `area=""` and see what happens.

Comment: @haim770 Adding the area fixed the problem, if you want to put that up as an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the `RenderAction` method is the **action** name, not the route name.

If you're rendering a View that is being generated using a Controller other than the one that defines the `SectionNavigation` Action, you'll have to specify the Controller name as well:

```
@Html.RenderAction("SecondNavigation", "YourControllerName").
```

If you're using Areas, you'll have to include the Area name as well:

```
@Html.RenderAction("SecondNavigation", "YourControllerName", new { Area = "MyAreaName" }).
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx)